# Google Docs: Extract numbers from cell, then sum them and display in another cell

Tags: google-sheets, extract

How can I write a formula for column B that will find numbers in A, then sum and display them in B?

Here's the example:

```
A                       B
Milan 2I + Marko 3I     5        what happened: 2+3=5, display 5
Nevena 6I + Umic 4I     10       what happened: 6+4=10, display 10
```

**Things I've tried**:

1. left, right, mid - can't work because names are random;
2. some    formulas which only give me the first number, without the second;
3. writing a UDF in C but failed to convert it to javascript code;
4. tried converting letters into 0s, then summing all the numbers in
   that one cell.

**Things I've thought of but don't know how to pull off**:

1. writing a formula that finds numbers that are followed by "I".

Note: The only constant thing in the cells is the fact that each number is followed by "I"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for finding the two numerical values, however it is a bit convoluted and I'm sure it can be abstracted to a few cells to make it easier and more efficient.  Assume A1 is the cell of your string.

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[0-9]I"),A1),LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[0-9]I"))-1)),VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,CONCATENATE("^.{",FIND(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[0-9]I"),A1)-1,"}[0-9]I",""),""),"[0-9]I"),A1),LEN(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,CONCATENATE("^.{",FIND(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[0-9]I"),A1)-1,"}[0-9]I"),""),"[0-9]I"))-1)))
```